# What does the 'b' mean here: ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'1.94E+02,2.02E-03'

Tags: python, numpy

When I run this:

```
import numpy as np

filename = "C:\\AV GIS\\ILS_measure\\sunshine_oct18.csv"
#filename = "C:\\AV GIS\\ILS_measure\\testcsv.csv"
data = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=0)
print(data.shape)
```

I get this:

```
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'1.94E+02,2.02E-03'
```

What does the 'b' mean before the "number-string" arguments?

I did hand-craft a .csv file to see if there was something peculiar to my real .csv data file, but even the simple .csv file produces the same error.

Comment: The `b` means it's a byte-string. But the exception message is mostly telling you that you didn't choose the right delimiter (the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) mention that it uses any whitespace as delimiter by default... but given the error message your csv uses comma). Does it work if you use `np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=0, delimiter=',')`?

Comment: I should make it clear that even with values like 123.45, 234.56 in the hand-crafted .csv file, the 'b' still appears before '123.45, 234.56' in the error message.

Comment: Mseifert is exactly right - it was my non-choice of delimiter.  Thank you very much!